# can someone tell me how to draw this figure? you can use any color you want

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

can someone tell me how to draw this figure? you can use any color you want
in order to Bettie understand it

Comment: on the site it is best if you ask a specific tex question, show what you have done and what TeX error you got and ask about that. Just asking someone to draw your artwork for you is likely to get closed as "too broad"

Answer (score 4):

I have made a quick MWE. Of course there is a lot of improvement, e.g. one could use loops etc. to automate a lot of things, and more nodes to nicely place texts more accurately. This is just a quick mock-up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[>=latex, ->] (-1,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
  \draw[>=latex, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,10) node[above] {$x_2$};

  \draw[dashed] (3,-1) -- ++(120:7);
  \draw[dashed] (4,-1) -- ++(120:9);
  \draw[dashed] (5,-1) -- ++(120:11);
  \draw[dashed] (6,-1) -- ++(120:13);

  \draw[>=latex, ->] (-1,5) -- ++(30:4) node[right] {direction of increasing $E$};

  \draw[shift={(2,3)},rotate=120] (0,0) ellipse (0.6 and 0.3);
  \draw[shift={(2,3)},rotate=120] (0,0) ellipse (0.8 and 0.5);
  \draw[shift={(2,3)},rotate=120] (0,0) ellipse (1   and 0.7);
  \draw[shift={(2,3)},rotate=120] (0,0) ellipse (1.2 and 0.9);
  \draw[shift={(2,3)},rotate=120] (0,0) ellipse (1.4 and 1.1);
  \draw[shift={(2,3)},rotate=120] (0,0) ellipse (1.6 and 1.3);
  \draw[shift={(2,3)},rotate=120] (0,0) ellipse (2 and 1.7);
  \draw[shift={(2,3)},rotate=120] (0,0) ellipse (2.5 and 2.2);

  \draw[thick] (6,0) node[below] {$b$} -- (3,3.5) -- (2,3);

  \begin{scope}[shift={(5,6)}]
  \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- ++(2,0) node[right] {isomean lines};
  \draw[thick] (0,-0.5) -- ++(2,0) node[right] {efficient portfolios};
  \draw (0,-1) -- ++(-45:1) -| (0,-1);
  \draw (2,-1.25) node[right] {attainable set};
  \draw (0.5,-2.5) ellipse (0.5 and 0.25);
  \draw (2,-2.5) node[right] {isovariance curves};
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE result]

Comment: thanks it s almost perfect you missed a strait line from the angle of the line b to the y-axes that you call "a" and "c" that is the point in the origin then it will be perfect thankss

Comment: you're right. But now you have the code and can make changes as well ;-) see marmot's comment here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453743/105991